# Enterprise Architect cannot check in package to TFS

Tags: tfs

I am trying out Enterprise Architect integration with Team Foundation Server using EA trial version. I was able to create a model with several sub packages using DBMS based and TFS 2013 as a version control system. I was able to check out a package successfully from TFS via EA. However I could not check in that same package, EA keeps showing me the error message:

```
   You cannot check-in package ‘blahblah’.
   The associated file ‘blahblah.xml’ is not currently checked-out by you.
```

I double checked the xml file from TFS Source Control via Visual Studio, it showed that the xml file was   “lock, edit” under my same credentials that was used in EA Version control settings. 
Interestingly, I was able to Undo check out successfully.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the version of the Team Foundation Server you are connecting to?  What version of Visual Studio are you running?

Answer (score 1):

I remember having this issue at work a couple of months ago. I don't have access to Enterprise Architect at the moment, nor am I in a position to recreate the problem to verify this solution, but I **do** remember how our team solved it:

The missing assumption to solving this, which may or may not be true in your case, is that your team went from the standard authentication method in the TFS settings, to SCC(or possibly the other way around). Now, assuming your credentials are the same in either method, you won't get an issue in Visual Studio, and can do everything apart from checking in in Enterprise Architect **until you update your TFS settings in Enterprise Architect**. Heck, everything will seem correct everywhere as your files IS checked out to you (no idea why this is permitted) but you cannot check in through the standard authentication method.

Comment: That was simple, and the extra assumption true in my case. Problem fixed - bounty awarded!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem which I was able to solve only by resynchronizing the status with the version control.

Right click on Model, click on "Package Control", click on "Re-sync status with VC provider".